# Featured Organisations and Groups

Tags: ckan

The config settings allow for specification of which organisation(s?) and group(s?) to feature on the home page.

e.g. `ckan.featured_groups = group_one`

> Defines a list of group names or group ids. This setting is used to
>   display a group and datasets on the home page in the default templates
>   (1 group and 2 datasets are displayed).

This infers plural groups/orgs can be featured?  If that is the case my questions are:

- do I simply specify a 2nd or 3rd group separating with a coma e.g.
  ckan.featured_groups = group_one, group_two
- if multiple groups/orgs are specified, how will they be displayed e.g. a random one chosen each time the homepage is loaded, or cycled
  through in order, or???

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify them using spaces as separators, not as you presume commas.

They will all be displayed, 2 to a row usually. e.g. Here's a random example with 2 promoted groups: http://bermuda.io/ You could customize the template to do whatever you like.